# How can I check out the server's response of unexpected frame type (ping)

Tags: jmeter

During I use the Jmeter Websocket request-response Sampler plugin to do the load test, the server returns the following errors:
(1)Sampler error: unexpected frame type (ping).
(2)Ping frame with application data 'T悅o'
But how can I check out the error and find the solution to the problems, thanks for your help:
[Responses from the WebSocket server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFcP7.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can add **WebSocket Ping/Pong Frame Filter** to your Test Plan and it will automatically discard [Ping](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6455#section-5.5.2) and/or [Pong](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6455#section-5.5.3) frames so you should stop seeing this error.

[image]

More information:

- [JMeter WebSocket Samplers](https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/src/master/) documentation (look for `Filters`)
- [JMeter WebSocket Samplers - A Practical Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-websocket-samplers-a-practical-guide)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I find the solution to the problem following your suggention